How to save leafmap as html so that it is interactive?
if I wanted to export this map m as an html file:
m = leafmap.Map() 
m.add_raster(filename, indexes=[3, 2, 1], vmin=0, vmax=100, layer_name="Landsat") 
m.add("layer_manager") 

m.to_html(outfile = "my_map.html")

When I do m.to_html(outfile = "my_map.html"), it exports it but incorrectly. The code works when at Google Collab I am able to use the gears and change the bands. When exported to HTML, though, I am unable to use the gears to interact with the map. Is exporting HTML the main problem?

Have you read this was possible somewhere? I suspect you are not understanding the software you are working with and haven't done due diligence to learn about it. If you go to the main documentation page about leafmap here, it is very clear with "A Python package for geospatial analysis and interactive mapping in a Jupyter environment." It doesn't say you can separate it out from an active Jupyter environment and expect it to work. The only think vaguely related I see that could be misinterpreted as such is, "Advanced programmers can also benefit ...

from leafmap for geospatial data analysis and building interactive web applications." But if you read the related information about that later on the page it is quite clear it involves frameworks that have active Python involved: "Building interactive web apps: Leafmap supports the development of interactive web applications using frameworks like Voila, Streamlit, and Solara." Luckily though you can probably due something along the line of what you want to achieve with Py.cafe using Streamlit or Solara. I think they plan to port the WASM-based Voila ...

 eventually but as far as I know it isn't available quite yet. It looks like you can even see an example with leafmap & solara working via py.cafe here. (You can see the code and fork it to adapt it as you wish here, or of course, just use it as a guide to do what you want.) Note py.cafe content isn't using an active server. The Python is being run deep in your browser via web-assembly (WASM). As such there are some limitations that you won't find using a typical, full Python kernel.

I just noted I had additional information related to that leafmap-solara example.:See https://x.com/giswqs/status/1800936945377591364  and https://x.com/maartenbreddels/status/1800941098652619209 . And there is a tutorial video: 'A PyCafe Tutorial: Building Interactive Web Apps for Geospatial Applications'. (Note the video was made a few months ago and PyCafe has developed fast since then and so don't get too hung up if the details you are seeing don't quite match what you see now.)
